# Good pattern? <X extends Exception> ... method() throws X

Tags: java, exception, generics, throws, checked-exceptions

Some background, then some questions.

I have only recently discovered that an interface (or class) may be generic in the type of (checked) exception that its methods may throw. For example:

```
interface GenericRunnable<X extends Exception> {
    void run() throws X;
}
```

The point is if you later instantiate this with, say, `IOException` and invoke the `run` method, the compiler knows you need to either catch `IOException` or mark it as thrown. Better still, if `X` was a `RuntimeException`, you don't need to handle it at all.

Here's a contrived example using the above interface, but it's basically a callback and should be quite common.

```
public <X extends Exception> void runTwice(GenericRunnable<X> runnable) throws X {
    runnable.run(); runnable.run();
}
...
public myMethod() throws MyException {
    runTwice(myRunnable);
}
```

We're calling a generic utility method `runTwice` (perhaps defined in an external library) to run our own specific method with a specific checked exception, and we don't lose any information about which specific checked exception might be thrown.

The alternative would have been to simply use `throws Exception` on both the `Runnable.run` method and the `runTwice` method. This would not restrict any implementation of the `Runnable` interface but the advantage of checked exceptions would be lost. Or there could have been no `throws` at all, also losing the advantage of checked exceptions and potentially forcing the implementation to wrap.

Because I had never seen `throws X`, maybe I've missed something. Furthermore, I have seen the callback example used as an argument against checked exceptions several times without it being refuted. (This question is not interested in the pros/cons of checked exceptions.)

**Is `throws X` generally a good idea? What are the pros and cons? Can you give some examples that either use `throws X` or didn't but should have?**

Basically, I would like some further insight. You might comment on the following examples.

- `OutputStream` throws `IOException` (perhaps `ByteArrayOutputStream` could extends `GenericOutputStream<RuntimeException>`)
- `Callable` / `Future.get`
- Commons Pool `borrowObject` / `makeObject`

(Since editing, I am not asking if these could/should have been designed differently in retrospect. Rather, would `throws X` be better than `throws Exception`.)

Comment: The stream classes couldn't have been designed like that, because they were designed before this feature was added (i.e., generics).

Comment: Guava's [`Throwables`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html) has some examples. But this question seems too broad. Try to refine your various questions throughout the post into something more focused.

Comment: Yep. Java has evolved over time. That means there are always going to be places in the older classes/feature where the newer ones _could_ have been used, but weren't available -- and since things work well enough without them, there hasn't been sufficient justification for doing so. You can of course implement your own wrappers/reinventions of the older classes to use the new features, and if they actually prove useful enough they may be adopted; that is in fact part of how the Java libraries have grown. But that happens only there's enough real added value, and enough demand, to justify it.

Comment: @keshlam And "no breakage" when done so ..

Comment: One downside of generics is that you need to design classes and APIs very careful so that you can keep the type around. Put more than 1 Generic<X> into a list with other Generic<Y> and you've lot it. I think that would in many cases mean that you could not actually use the type but would have to deal with Generic<?>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this pattern all the time, mostly for functional-style java.

Pros:

1. You can have several flavors of a higher-order pattern like Visitor, to wit:

   ```
   interface ExceptionalVoidVisitor< E extends Exception > {
       void handleA( A a ) throws E;
       void handleB( B b ) throws E;
   }
   interface VoidVisitor extends ExceptionalVoidVisitor< RuntimeException > {}
   interface ExceptionalVisitor< T, E extends Exception > {
       T handleA( A a ) throws E;
       T handleB( B b ) throws E;
   }
   interface Visitor< T > extends ExceptionalVisitor< T, RuntimeException > {}
   ```
2. Your client can declare a base exception class for all the exceptions he might throw and you end up with a fully general library.

Cons:

1. As you've discovered, there is no way to handle an exception of generic type; you must allow it to escape.
2. The other option is to accept a generator of E, which can be awkward for clients.